# Вывод денег с Google Play на Qiwi кошелёк

Tags: android, google-play

Можно ли выводить деньги с продажи приложений в Google Play на анонимный Qiwi кошелёк?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вывести деньги можно 3-мя способами ([справка](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772229?hl=ru)):

1. Банковский перевод
2. Чек
3. Переводов через систему "Рапида"

Вам нужен 3 способ, т.к. Рапида - принадлежит QIWI. 
Вам останется в Рапиде настроить шаблон, по которому каждый перевод из Google Play будет автоматом переводится на указанный вами в шаблоне QIWI кошелек.

Вот и все.

P.S: Нужно только учесть то, что ваш аккаунт в Рапиде должен быть персонализирован, т.е. нужно съездить в офис с паспортом и подтвердить личность - процедура занимает 10 минут.

Comment: Не обязательно в офис, в любой банк-партнер и предоставить паспорт и около 300 рублей, 150 из которых вроде вернутся, и потом вы можете из Рапиды выводить деньги без комиссии на Qiwi

Answer (score 2):

Нет, нельзя. Только на долларовый счёт с банке РФ. Туда нужно предоставить реальные свои данные.